# Weird number boxes for output in terminal running GCC for C Programing

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc

This code works on other machines but when I add a `' '` to the `putchar` output I get weird characters.

Some general information:

- Running in a VM on Windows 8
- Running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- Installed the basic package for C development using GCC
- The output sometimes works and sometimes doesn't when I modify the program but I'm sure it is a problem with something I installed or Ubuntu because it works in other machines.  I don't think the output for the terminal recognizes the `' '`
- I am also new to programming C

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRl1s.png)

[image]

The code:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if (c == ' ') {
        while ((c = getchar()) == ' ');
        putchar(' ');
        if (c == EOF) break;
    }
    putchar(c);
}
```

Comment: OH wow, I just assumed that stack exchange uses code tags and automatically does line breaks. I don't know to edit either. Sorry. The output picture pretty much explains it though.

Comment: No worries, I just fixed it for you. For next time, you can find some formatting tips [here](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting). Unfortunately though this is a bit too programming related for this site, you'd be better off deleting this and posting on [so] instead. Make sure you add some more information though like what the "basic package for C development" is and which gcc version you're using, which Ubuntu version, some information on your locale and terminal encoding settings etc.

Comment: What do you mean by 'add a `' '` to the `putchar`'?  Is the code you show the code that produces the output from the image?

Comment: When I wrap your code with `#include <stdio.h>` and `int main(void) {` at the top, and `}` at the bottom, and compile it on a new install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (upgraded earlier today from 13.10), I get the behaviour I expect.  Input `This is the input string with  multiple   spaces     on occasion     .` and output `This is the input string with multiple spaces on occasion .`

Comment: This code snippet is fine, try posting a complete program that shows the problem.